# Can I somehow make my bot send a message in a specific text channel when it goes offline?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I already have a function which allows the bot to send a message when it is online, but if the bot is offline I want it to send a message saying that it is now offline so that people can check the activity of the bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot because there is no way for the program to know before the bot goes offline, unless you specifically make it go offline yourself, why can they not just check if the bot has an online/invisible status?

Another option is to do a `ping` command, if the bot responds, its online if not its offline:

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
   if(msg.content === "!ping") {
     return msg.reply("Online!");
   }
});
```